# Assets uploads Failing, Server requirements

Tags: assets, uploads

I'm running EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.4

I have massive upload problems on several websites running assets. assets fails to upload certain images. i get a notification «Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response. Please check the server settings»

we had this issue in previous threads. i set the all concerning folders to 777. i checked upload paths and .htaccess. everything seems ok. i can upload files like pdf with the same settings.

i believe there must be some server setting that is wrong but i can't find the requirements for assets. can anybody help?

Comment: Samuel,
Is it just for certain images in the same folder? Might be a server setting. I would check the upload AJAX request response bodies, but if that sounds too far out for you, try shooting an email to support@pixelandtonic.com and we'll see what we can do about that.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem. it turned out that there was a wrong FastCGI implemented on the server. My host implemented a new version of FastCGI and now the upload with assets works like it should.